How can I specify the directory I want to get using the os library?
I have a directory called "Data" and inside it I have 35 other directories with another bunch of directories each. I need to check if these last directories have .txt files and, if so, I want to get the name of the specific directory that is one of the aforementioned 35. After this, I want to use the pandas library to generate a "yes/no" spreadsheet with "yes" for the directories (one of the 35) that have .txt files and "no" for the directories (one of the 35) that do not have .txt files.
For now, I could write the following as a test:
import os
w=[]
w=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Name\New\Data')
tot=len(w)
a=0
while a!=tot:
    print(w[a])
    a=a+1

Which gives me the names of the 35 main directories I am interested in (Folder1, Folder2, Folder3, ..., Folder35)
AND
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Name\New\Data'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            print(root)

But it results in a list with the whole path, like "C:\Users\Name\New\Data\Folder1\Folder1-1", and what I really need is to compare the name "Folder1" to the entries of the aforementioned list.
How can I check if the element in "w[]" corresponds to the name in "root"?

dirs already has a list of the subdir names.  Why not use that?

To check if each main directory contains any .txt files in its subdirectories, we can combine the logic you've started with and streamline it to match only the main directory name (one of the 35).
Here's the code to achieve this and generate a yes/no spreadsheet using pandas.
import os
import pandas as pd

main_dir = r'C:\Users\Name\New\Data'
main_folders = os.listdir(main_dir)
results = {folder: "No" for folder in main_folders}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main_dir):
    if any(file.endswith('.txt') for file in files):
        main_folder_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(root))        
        if main_folder_name in results:
            results[main_folder_name] = "Yes"

df = pd.DataFrame(list(results.items()), columns=['Folder', 'Has_txt_file'])
output_path = r'C:\Users\Name\New\output.xlsx'
df.to_excel(output_path, index=False)

I hope this will help you a little.

It has helped me A LOT! I spent the day trying to solve the problem in a different way, but you did it exactly how I wanted to (I just don't have the skills to do so by myself yet, I think haha). Thanks a lot!

glad to hear that it was helpful. happy coding! :)

You may use os.path.split(os.path.split("C:\Users\Name\New\Data\Folder1\Folder1-1")[0])[1] construction: it will produce "Folder1"
Sure, if I understood right what your issue is.

I did not help because (if I understood correctly) os.path.split() splits the path into a "head" and "tail", but what I really need is to get is the name of only one of the folders (which is a variable for me, as it will be different according to the users' need), put it inside a tuple and compare it to a previously created tuple, one with the name of all the 35 folders. It was good to know about the existence of this function though, it may be useful in the future!
